# JQM Flickering in Safari in standalone mode

Tags: jquery-mobile, safari

Am having the following issue:

Created an ASP.NET MVC 4 HTML5 web application for a mobile web app.  When running on an iPhone 4 in standalone mode (ie. when the web app is launched from a home screen button instead of browsed to in Safari) I notice an unwanted and annoying flickering when transitioning to most of my pages.  This does not happen at all if I launch Safari and browse to the web URL.  It only happens when launching the web app from a button on the home screen.  This is running iOS 6.1.3.  I certainly don't want my users having to see this flicker when using my web application. What is causing this annoying behavior and how can I correct it?

I have found similar threads discussing this issue and tried all solutions offered and none of them worked.